# Make chrome cache decoded images

Tags: javascript, image, performance, google-chrome, html5-canvas

I'm working on a project using Adobe Animate graphics exported as HTML.
This uses createjs behind the scene and I have noticed really poor performance when using full-screen (1080x1920) png images in the graphic.

The main issue is that decoding these png images takes a long time however by using preloadjs I've been able to preload images which works fine in firefox but not in chrome.

It seems that whenever accessing images chrome will always "decode" the image.   Is it possible to override this behaviour?
Ultimately I will be rendering the graphics in a custom CEF instance so I have a fair amount of control.

I've created a simple version of this to reproduce the issue without using createjs/preloadjs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <button id="play-but" onclick="play();" disabled>Play</button>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="1920" height="1080"></canvas>
    <canvas id="hiddencanvas" width="1920" height="1080"></canvas>
    <script>
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        var hiddencanvas = document.getElementById('hiddencanvas');
        var hiddenctx = hiddencanvas.getContext('2d');

        var images = [];
        var imagesToLoad = 110; // set this to the number of images
        var index = 0;

        function play() {
            setInterval(draw, 40);
        }

        // The function to display the current image
        function draw() {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            ctx.drawImage(images[index], 0, 0);

            // Update the index
            index = (index + 1) % images.length;
        }

        {
            // Pre-load the images
            for (var i = 0; i < imagesToLoad; i++) {
                var img = new Image();
                img.onload = function () {
                    imagesToLoad--;
                    if (imagesToLoad == 0) {
                        document.getElementById("play-but").disabled = false;
                    }
                    createImageBitmap(this)
                        .then(imgBitmap => {
                            // Draw the image to the canvas
                            // Here we are drawing at position (0, 0), you should adjust this according to your needs
                            hiddenctx.drawImage(imgBitmap, 0, 0);
                        })
                    // Start the image slideshow when all images are loaded
                }
                img.src = 'images/frame' + String(i).padStart(6, '0') + '.png';
                images.push(img);
            }
        }

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is what firefox rendering timeline looks like.
[image]

Here is chromes timeline.  Notice that "image decode" is called still in the play stage while in firefox it seems to be reusing the cached image

[image]